# Changing colors in Twitter Bootstrap on Rails 3.1 with SASS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, less, twitter-bootstrap

[Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/#) is a cool stylesheet toolkit by Twitter based on LESS. I don't use LESS however I am using the [twitter-bootstrap-rails](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) gem and it seems to be all working fine. However I am unable to figure out how to change the colors in the CSS, particularly the link color.

My further research seems to point that the gem only provides a pre-rendered CSS file with fixed colors declarations and not variables that could be changed in one place. I would love to be able to just change the colors by changing a variable like `$linkColor = #00ff00`

Does anyone have any idea as to how to do the color changes efficiently throughout the UI without using LESS?

I want to avoid using LESS since Rails 3.1 already uses SASS, but if anyone here thinks its not a big deal using both, I'm open to suggestions however.

Any help or suggestion will be much appreciated

Comment: does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I am still using LESS, through this gem https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails-bootstrap I would like to avoid having the change the variables in LESS to change the color while the rest of my app is in the Rails 3.1 standard SASS/SCSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a reasonably popular conversion of Bootstrap to SASS <sup>[1](https://rubygems.org/gems/bootstrap-sass), [2](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass)</sup>, which allows you to define your own variables if you use a custom helper manifest, rather than the one included in the gem.

As an example, in the head of `application.css.scss`:

```
@import "bootstrap/reset";
@import "bootstrap/variables";

// overwrite variables here

@import "bootstrap/mixins";

@import "bootstrap/scaffolding";

@import "bootstrap/type";
@import "bootstrap/forms";
@import "bootstrap/tables";
@import "bootstrap/patterns";

// rest of your manifest
```

You can overwrite [the supported variables](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables.css.scss) before importing the rest of the bootstrap files, and these will also be accessible through the rest of your SCSS.

Comment: This is great stuff, Thomas. Thanks for putting it out there!

Comment: @Thomas McDonald I wonder if there are examples of use of overriding bootstrap's mixins (such as border-radius) with 'bootstrap-sass' somewhere?

Comment: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap/reset. Any idea how to do it properly?

Answer (score 2):

I found a good compromise: I keep the .less source under a folder, and I have a guard command to compile this to css directly to vendor/assets.

This allows me to use the less mixins inside an additional .less where it makes sense (ie: to add a new color), and keep the rest of the app in scss.

I did that because I really wanted to rely directly on the twitter boostrap source, not on a scss adaptation which may lag behind later on at some point.

Contact me if you need more details, I plan a blog post on that.

Comment: Please post the link to that blog post here, it will be very useful.

Comment: @alik I will definitely post it here, planned real soon now

Answer (score 0):

I found two separate SCSS versions of the bootstrap files. Both (in the preboot.scss file) allow you to just change a variable for things like linkColor.

- [bootstrap.scss](https://github.com/yuukinajima/bootstrap.scss)
- [twitter-bootstrap-scss](https://github.com/teddyzetterlund/twitter-bootstrap-scss)

Now, how to integrate those into your own app, I'm not sure. But it appears it can be done with SCSS if you want to avoid LESS.

Comment: That integration is turning out to be quite an issue, and it also looks like both these versions of Bootstrap are out of date since needed the latest one. I was also having to include another gem to get the Bootstrap JS part to working, since a lot of bootstrap doesn't work properly without its JS counterpart. So I switched back to using less-rails-bootstrap gem, until I can find a better SCSS solution. Please let me know if you know of any